# What is the best way to index one specific key/value in a JSONB entry in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I would like to use indexes to speed up search in my Postgres database. It's the first time I'm using indexes so I'm not really sure what's the best way to do this.

The table, in which I want to use indexes, looks like this:

```
| id [id]             | data [jsonb]   |
|---------------------+------------------------|
| a11                 | [                      |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p11",   |
|                     |     "position": 4      |
|                     |   },                   |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p12",   |
|                     |     "position": 2      |
|                     |   }                    |
|                     | ]                      |
| ------------------- | ---------------------- |
| a12                 | [                      |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p13",   |
|                     |     "position": 3      |
|                     |   },                   |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p14",   |
|                     |     "position": 6      |
|                     |   }                    |
|                     | ]                      |
| ------------------- | ---------------------- |
| a13                 | [                      |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p11",   |
|                     |     "position": 3      |
|                     |   },                   |
|                     |   {                    |
|                     |     "itemId": "p14",   |
|                     |     "position": 2      |
|                     |   }                    |
|                     | ]                      |
```

This table has thousands of entries and what I want to be able to do, is to quickly find all the entries in which a specific itemId is contained. For example: looking for "p11" would, in this case, return the entries with the ids "a11" and "a13".

What's the best way to do this?

My take would be to create an index-table using GIN-indexes and indexing **only the itemIds** of the data-column. Position and other data doesn't need to be indexed.

Would this be a proper usecase for GIN-indexes? If not, what should I use instead? And how would the SQL statements look like?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward approach would be to create a GIN index on the whole JSON:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin (data);
```

and query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM tab WHERE data @> '[ { "itemId": "p11" } ]';
```

If you want to keep the size of the index as small as possible and make the query as fast as possible, you could instead use a B-tree index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab (id) WHERE data @> '[ { "itemId": "p11" } ]';
```

That partial index would support the above query even better, but it will probably only be useful for that one query. You have to decide if the benefit outweighs the loss of generality or not.

Comment: You could also create the partial index `CREATE INDEX ON tab USING btree (data->>'itemid')` and which should be used by the query `SELECT * FROM tab WHERE data->>'itemid' = 'p11'`. This BTREE index should be smaller and faster than GIN.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I will go with @Edouard's approach, since that is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Edouard But the JSON is an array, so `data ->> 'itemId'` won't be correct...

Comment: @Lanrenz : you are right, BTREE doesn't work for arrays ... so back to your solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So just to clarify for myself: As long as the JSON is inside an array it's not possible to target a specific key when indexing, right? Or is it maybe possible to use something like an SQL/PgSQL-function to loop through the array while indexing? Not sure though, how something like that might look.

Comment: I showed you the options. If that doesn't make you happy, perhaps you should make the effort and choose a better data model without JSON arrays.